# What's wrong with this regex to match URLs?

Tags: c, regex, url, cgi

I'm having a bit of difficulty setting up a regex to match a URL using the regex.h library in C.  I have a working IP regex that I was hoping to convert to match a simple string such as `www.alphanumerictext12.com|edu|org`.  Something is wrong with my syntax in the regex definition itself.

Below is the working IPREGEX code and my attempted URL regex.

```
#define IPEXPR    "([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})"
#define URLEXPR "(www)\\.((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))\\.(com|edu|org)"

regex_t regex;

if(regcomp(&regex, IPEXPR, REG_EXTENDED) != 0)
  return 0;

if(regexec(&regex, inputURL, 0, NULL, 0) != 0)
  return 0;
```

Comment: Okay, I have since updated my regex to:  "^(www|www1){1}\\.[a-z0-9]+[_]*[-]*[a-z0-9]*\\.(com|edu|org)$"  which is working great for anything that I throw at it except case insensitivity...my compiler didn't care for: "(?i)^(www|www1){1}\\.[a-z0-9]+[_]*[-]*[a-z0-9]*\\.(com|edu|org)$"  Suggestions to improve this string?  Thanks again everybody, CB

Comment: I've tried adding the REG_ICASE flag to regexec() and regcomp() but no luck....suggestions?  CB

Comment: REG_ICASE should work. Have you tried regcomp(&regex, URLEXPR, REG_EXTENDED|REG_ICASE)?

And also, can you tell us what is your goal at higher level? You are constructing really really strange regexp... It works on just a small part of domain names...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
"www\\.[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*\\.(com|edu|org)"
```

I removed the `[0-9]+` and replaced `[a-z][a-z]*` with `[a-z]+`.

Comment: I want this to be case insensitive, would the following be preferable then? :  "www\\.[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\.(com|edu|org)"

Comment: You could do that, but that won't permit `.COM` or `.eDu` as a TLD. You could enable case insensitive matching by adding the `(?i)` flag in front of your regex: `"(?i)www\\.[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*\\.(com|edu|org)"` assuming `(?i)` is supported by the regex library you're using.

Comment: I am using regex.h in c on Ubuntu.  I'll give (?i) a test.


"www\\.[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*\\.(com|edu|org)" is working delightfully, now I need to add in the characters - and _  Where do I drop them in?  I attempted to add them in as such: [a-z0-9-_] but it failed.  What key point am I glazing over here?  Thanks all, CB

Comment: The `-` might be seen as the range indicator by the regex library. Try `[a-z0-9_-]` instead (st the end, it should not be taken for a range indicator). Or else, try escaping the `-` like this: `[a-z0-9_\-]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `(?: )`, You need just `(www)\\.([a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)\\.(com|edu|org)`.

Btw, your inner expression says: "at least one alpha character, then at least one numeric character, then any alphanumeric characters". Is it what you mean? If so, you can make it a little bit shorter: `[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*`.

Comment: "at least one alpha character, then at least one numeric character, then any alphanumeric characters". Is it what you mean?  
    No, that would be a mistake.

I will give your regex a try and report back, thank you!

CB

Comment: Then you may prefer [a-z]+[a-z0-9]*, but beware, domain names can start with digit :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using [`inet_pton()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/inet_ntop.html) which is a standard POSIX function (replacing `inet_aton()`) and handles both IPv4 and IPv6 address formats.

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand the use of this.  Would it be a more dignified way of checking the validity of an IP address versus the regex that I currently employ? (Defined above as IPEXPR)  

CB

Comment: yes, especially since IPv6 has abbreviated forms that inet_pton will handle.  It's not just 0-9 and .

Answer (score -2):

From [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have
>   two problems.

What I mean is: are you sure a regular expression is the best way to solve your problem? Maybe you can test whether the string is a URL with some more lightweigth method?

---

*Edit*

The following program on my computer, with output redirected to `/dev/null`, prints (to `stderr`)

```
rx time: 1.730000
lw time: 0.920000
```

**Program Listing:**

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int goodurl_rx(const char *buf) {
  static regex_t rx;
  static int done = 0;
  int e;

  if (!done) {
    done = 1;
    if ((e = regcomp(&rx, "^www\\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*\\.(com|edu|org)$", REG_EXTENDED)) != 0) {
      printf("Error %d compiling regular expression.\n", e);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
  return !regexec(&rx, buf, 0, NULL, 0);
}

int goodurl_lw(const char *buf) {
  if (*buf++ != 'w') return 0;
  if (*buf++ != 'w') return 0;
  if (*buf++ != 'w') return 0;
  if (*buf++ != '.') return 0;
  if (!isalpha((unsigned char)*buf++)) return 0;
  while (isalnum((unsigned char)*buf)) buf++;
  if (*buf++ != '.') return 0;
  if ((*buf == 'c') && (*(buf+1) == 'o') && (*(buf+2) == 'm') && (*(buf+3) == 0)) return 1;
  if ((*buf == 'e') && (*(buf+1) == 'd') && (*(buf+2) == 'u') && (*(buf+3) == 0)) return 1;
  if ((*buf == 'o') && (*(buf+1) == 'r') && (*(buf+2) == 'g') && (*(buf+3) == 0)) return 1;
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  clock_t t0, t1, t2;
  char *buf[] = {"www.alphanumerics.com", "ww2.alphanumerics.com", "www.alphanumerics.net"};
  int times;

  t0 = clock();
  times = 1000000;
  while (times--) {
    printf("    %s: %s\n", buf[0], goodurl_rx(buf[0])?"pass":"invalid");
    printf("    %s: %s\n", buf[1], goodurl_rx(buf[1])?"pass":"invalid");
    printf("    %s: %s\n", buf[2], goodurl_rx(buf[2])?"pass":"invalid");
  };
  t1 = clock();
  times = 1000000;
  while (times--) {
    printf("    %s: %s\n", buf[0], goodurl_lw(buf[0])?"pass":"invalid");
    printf("    %s: %s\n", buf[1], goodurl_lw(buf[1])?"pass":"invalid");
    printf("    %s: %s\n", buf[2], goodurl_lw(buf[2])?"pass":"invalid");
  } while (0);
  t2 = clock();

  fprintf(stderr, "rx time: %f\n", (double)(t1-t0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  fprintf(stderr, "lw time: %f\n", (double)(t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, In this case I do believe a regex is the best answer, yet I am certainly open to valid suggestions.   I am inputting a web address from a user in the general form: www.alphanumerics.com.  Could you suggest a more lightweight method?

Comment: pmg, almost certanly this function is intended for validating user input, so a tiny fraction of a second really doesn't matter here.

But what about development time, readability, supportability etc?Slight changes will require you to rewrite your code, ending up with home-made FSA.

Comment: For this simple example, I agree that the regular expression function is easier to deal with. Someday, however, when you want to "accept" `co.uk` and `net.au`, invalidate `ads*.*` but not `cads*.*`, ..., ...; neither will be good. When this happens a parser is the best option, but IMVHO, a solution based on regular expressions tends to keep using regular expressions: more of them and more awkward.